# exception missing class when i run "check_jmxeval.bat" in CMD to test the setup

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, nagios

I'am trying to add jmx checks to Nagwin(Nagios for windows), but after I unzip the files inside "jmxeval-1.2.6-dist.zip" and put the files in my nagwin plugin directory and run the "check_jmxeval.bat" it gives class not found error.

I've setup the "JAVA_HOME" to the Java -JDK in C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_79

I followed the steps in (https://code.google.com/p/jmxeval/wiki/GettingStarted) to get started with jmxeval plugin.

these are the files to be put in the nagwin plugin directory (C:\Nagwin_x86\plugins)

1. jmxeval-.jar
2. check_jmxeval.bat (for windows)

And here is the error that i still get in CMD.

```
C:\Nagwin_x86\plugins>check_jmxeval.bat
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kohsuke/args4j/CmdLineException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 6 more
```

"check_jmxeval.bat" content

```
@echo off
::
:: JMXEval execution script
::
:: Syntax: check_jmxeval.bat <config-xml-file> [<options>]
::
:: If JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set, uncomment the following
:: line and set the value as the path to root of the Java directory 
::
:: JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
::
:: Executes JMXEval
::
set BASE_DIR=%~dp0
set LIB_DIR=%BASE_DIR%\lib
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath %BASE_DIR%\jmxeval-1.2.6.jar;%LIB_DIR%\args4j-2.0.16.jar com.adahas.tools.jmxeval.App %*
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness you might add the contents of [check_jmxeval.bat](https://code.google.com/p/jmxeval/source/browse/trunk/src/main/script/check_jmxeval.bat) into the question. BTW the comment in the bat file says there is a mandatory parameter `config-xml-file`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the comments of the same bat file. and I'am looking for the config-xml-file parameters.

Comment: set LIB_DIR="%BASE_DIR%\lib"
        "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath %BASE_DIR%\jmxeval-1.2.6.jar";"%LIB_DIR%\args4j-2.0.16.jar" com.adahas.tools.jmxeval.App %*         I hope i got it right.

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -classpath "%BASE_DIR%\jmxeval-1.2.6.jar;%LIB_DIR%\args4j-2.0.16.jar" com.adahas.tools.jmxeval.App %*` and don't add quotes to the previous assignments.

Comment: I didn't find the xml-config file and i think it is an option. the plugin didn't work with adding quotes in it's content arguments. it gave exactly the same exception. It is asking for a class, and i think it has to do something with the args4j-2.0.16.jar file. I don't know how to add this jar file, i tried placing it in here "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib".  Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

The bat file running jmxeval has been broken as it hasn't been updated correctly to setup the classpath when a new dependent library was introduced.

This is fixed now.